# Efficient way to compare three text files in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, comparison, text-files

I have a vb.net program in which I must compare three text files(two against one) and verify that they are all same. Even if there is one change I must know where the change is, which text file and which line. The format of the text file is like this

```
timestamp|ab|someval
timestamp|ab|someval1
timestamp|bc|someval2
timestamp|bc|someval2
```

All the text files are like this with a same format, but the values might be in a different order. For instance

```
text1.txt

ts|av|2
ts|ab|3
ts|av|4

text2.txt

ts|av|4
ts|ab|3
ts|av|2
```

This should not fail as they have the same values. Can any one tell me how can I go about this?

Comment: Have you considered using an existing diff program, and simply invoking it from your program?

Comment: With the constraint that the lines in the file can appear out-of-order, your choice of third party programs probably becomes limited.  You could pre-sort the files, but you'd lose information as to which line numbers were in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have, in effect, is potentially three different permutations of the same items. So if the text files were files of integers, then these three would be considered identical:

`1,2,3`
`3,2,1`
`2,1,3`

but `1,2,4` would not be.

If the file is small enough to fit into memory, then you can use a simple `HashSet(of String)` (I hope I got the VB syntax right).  Note that you only have to keep the contents of ONE file in memory. The others are read line-by-line.

For the first file, read each line into an object (or perhaps just save it as a string) and add it to your `HashSet`. Now, for each of the other two files (assuming the `hashSet` is called `file1Data`):

```
int lineNum = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    ++lineNum;
    if (!file1Data.Contains(line))
    {
        // error here
    }
}
```

If the files aren't small enough to fit into memory, then I see no other option than to do an external sort on each file, then either use an existing diff program, or write a simple merge comparison.

Comment: Thanks... I dont think you have the right syntax for vb.net here. Also I dont think i need to use a hashset. A simple array list would do the trick for me. But i was dumb enough not to think of this at first. Thanks again

Comment: @swordfish: If you have large files, a program using a hashset would run much faster, and really isn't (much) more complicated.

Comment: @swordfish: If you use an array then you'll have to sort it, and every check will require a binary search. If you don't sort it then every lookup will be a linear search and that will take a very long time. A `HashSet` will be much faster. Sorry for the C#, by the way. But you should be able to convert without much trouble, since it's mostly just using BCL objects.